# Is RewriteMod for WordPress site: site.ro -> site.com/?lang=ro possible?

Tags: htaccess, apache

I'm not much of a WordPress specialist - is it possible to redirect new domain to the same site, but with `?lang=ro` query parameter so it shows the old site with selected language?

Result I want:

- site.com -> showing the site
- site.ro -> showing the in specified language and maintaining the links as they are on site.com, but while using site.ro

I have also option of using (via outdated plugin):

- pre-path (site.com/ro/)
- pre-domain (ro.site.com)
  but they will require additional configuration and this plugin is already outdated so I'd rather not change anything in that regard to not break anything.

Comment: [You should do this in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/412607/is-rewritemod-for-wordpress-site-site-ro-site-com-lang-ro-possible), not Apache. [As mentioned on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75018768/is-rewritemod-for-wordpress-site-site-ro-site-com-lang-ro-possible), to do this in Apache: "in specified language and maintaining the links as they are on site.com, but while using site.ro" would require full access to your server-config (not .htaccess) to configure a reverse proxy, which is a considerable overhead considering this is all happening on one server.